# I've linked an external party to my Google BigQuery instance through an API key. How can I control how much of my data they're able to see?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a database in Google BigQuery that contains confidential client data. My team's recently partnered with a 3rd-party data provider who will feed real-time data into our BigQuery instance via an API I provided (source: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python)

We want to make sure this 3rd-party provider can only access/view the data they're sending us, and not the data in our client database. Is there a way to set permissions to control what they can see in our account?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, check out Authorized Views in BigQuery. I believe this is what it was designed for.

[Creating an authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views)

Essentially, you set up a filtered query that you give the third party access to. Since it runs whatever filter that you set in the View Query, they only see what you want them to see.